# transformClassesWithJarMergingForRelease Fail

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to Generate Signed APK and I'm getting this error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':MyApp:transformClassesWithJarMergingForRelease'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/annotation/ColorRes.class
```

Any idea about this error message?

build.grade File:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.app.colorseverywhere"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 18
    multiDexEnabled true
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
}

}

dependencies {
    compile project(":androidsupportv7appcompat")
    compile project(":googleplayservices_lib")
    compile project(":touchListViewPlaytube")
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.3'
    compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
    compile files('libs/android-async-http-1.4.5.jar')
    compile files('libs/appbrain-applift-sdk-10.41.jar')
    compile files('libs/applovin-sdk-5.4.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/commons-lang-2.6.jar')
    compile files('libs/FlurryAnalytics-4.1.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/MMSDK.jar')
    compile files('libs/simple-xml-2.7.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/SOMAAndroidSDK6.1.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/universal-image-loader-1.9.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/xstream-1.4.7.jar')
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:+'
    compile files('libs/MobFox-Android-SDK-Core-3.2.5f.jar')
}
```

Comment: provide your gradle files without them it is hard to help

Comment: @RalphBergmann Just add the build.gradle

Comment: why do you add most of your libs as project / jar and not the normal way?